# Android colors are "mixed" on phone, solid on tablet

Tags: android, colors

I've got a simple Bitmap based fill algorithm that takes a Color and fills an area of a Bitmap with that color.  The problem that I'm seeing is that on my phone, an HTC Evo 4G, when the algorithm fills the bitmap, it's actually placing different colored pixels, while on a Galaxy Tab 10.1, the same code places a single color throughout the area.  Some code will make this clearer.

```
Bitmap dst = ...
int replacementColor = Color.GRAY; //Color.DKGRAY and Color.LTGRAY also show the issue

dst.setPixel(x, y, replacementColor);
if(dst.getPixel(x, y) != replacementColor)
{
    //Only gets triggered on the HTC Evo, not the Galaxy Tab
    Log.d("Pixels don't match");
}
```

If I take a screenshot of the device, and zoom in, you can clearly see the checkerboard pattern on the Evo, and a solid color on the Galaxy Tab.

I'm sure that this is a well known graphics problem, but I don't know the right terminology to find out how (and if) I can work around it.  The problem comes in when I try to fill that area a second time - my algorithm is matching colors, and only filling areas of the same color, but after filling with gray on the phone, I don't have a solid region of the same color so the algorithm doesn't fill the entire region.

Any ideas how I can force a solid color on an Evo, or identify that this problem is occuring so I can appropriately fill the area a second time?  Maybe I need to look at the neighboring pixels, and average the color?

Comment: It sounds like [dithering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dithering#Digital_photography_and_image_processing). I don't know about Android or these devices specifically, but in general dithering is an attempt to approximate a color that cannot be exactly reproduced using the palette available.

Comment: Do you need pixel level precision? Can you just draw a colored rect into the Bitmap?

Comment: Is it doing anti-aliasing because your set up for the wrong pixel density?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dithering was indeed the culprit here, as rsutphin mentioned.  As it turns out, the bitmaps that I was filling had a Bitmap.Config of RGB_565.  Copying those bitmaps and setting the config to ARGB_8888 fixed this dithering issue.

```
Bitmap bmp = orig.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

Thanks!

Comment: One thing to be aware of (this problem came up for me again) is that unless your bitmap has an alpha channel, using a form of Bitmap.createBitmap where you can't specifically set the Config will result in a config of RGB_565 being set - so make sure you can set this value on your bitmap, or that your bitmap has an alpha channel.